# Fast way to download many small webpages?

Tags: linux, wget, curl, aria2

I need to download lots of small pages as fast as possible. Average size for one page is 3kb. There are millions of pages. First, I tried `curl` but it was way too slow, probably because it was waiting for the server to respond a request, then execute the same process for the next page.

```
curl -O "http://website.com/pages/[0000001-1000000].html"
```

---

Edit: After doing some tests, I observed these results. I am always open to more suggestions. I would like to improve speed even more.

### Comparison 1: (dns vs. no dns)

**slower:**

```
curl -O "http://website.com/pages/[1-1000].html" -s -S
```

**faster:**

```
curl -O "http://90.111.123.222/pages/[1-1000].html" -s -S
```

*When downloading lots of small pages, dns delays are critical.*

### Comparison 2: (using curl sequence vs. "seq")

**slower:**

```
curl -O "http://90.111.123.222/pages/{1}.html" -s -S ::: $(seq 1 1000)
```

**faster:**

```
curl -O "http://90.111.123.222/pages/[1-1000].html" -s -S
```

### Comparison 3: (parallel execution)

**slower:**

```
time parallel -j 5 curl -O \'"http://90.111.123.222/pages/{1}.html"\'
-S -s ::: $(seq 1 1000)
```

**faster:**

```
( time curl -O "http://90.111.123.222/pages/[1-200].html" -s -S &
  time curl -O "http://90.111.123.222/pages/[201-400].html" -s -S &
  time curl -O "http://90.111.123.222/pages/[401-600].html" -s -S &
  time curl -O "http://90.111.123.222/pages/[601-800].html" -s -S &
  time curl -O "http://90.111.123.222/pages/[801-1000].html" -s -S & )
```

*Btw, obviously running more instances will improve speed for both methods to some point.*

Comment: curl is more slow couse it handle the protocol to use, wget is another option, but im not sure if using it will be more faster.

Comment: I think both curl and wget will be slow unless there is a way to run them in parallel. When I ran 5 curl commands in different ranges at the same time, the total speed jumped to 4-5x but it wasn't a practical way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You speed this up by chunking your operation into several smaller operations. For example, you could create 10 curl processes and background them:

```
curl -O "http://website.com/pages/0[000000-999999].html" &
curl -O "http://website.com/pages/1[000000-999999].html" &
curl -O "http://website.com/pages/2[000000-999999].html" &
...
```

and so on.

However, the smarter and more flexible solution might want to use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) so multiple files can be downloaded in parallel, with parallel handling the task distribution.

install it with your package manager of choice then it would be something simply like

```
parallel -j 10 curl -O "http://website.com/pages/{1}" ::: $(seq -w 1000000)
```

which is a lot more elegant

Comment: my urls contains "&" character and this cause problem when using parallel.
It works fine when using it without parallel: 
 `curl -O "http://website.com/page1.php?varx=1&vary=0"`
but this one doesnt read the link after "&" :
`parallel -j 10 curl -O "http://website.com/page{1}.php?varx=1&vary=0" ::: $(seq -w 1000000)`

Comment: using `'/ `before and after the link solved my problem: `parallel -j 10 curl -O '/ "http://website.com/page{1}.php?varx=1&vary=0"'/  ::: $(seq -w 1000000)`

Comment: You can also escape special shell characters (&, ;, etc.) with a backtick ( \ )

Comment: If you "know" the URLs to all your pages, you can try to use [Parameterized URI support](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#parameterized-uri-support) of `aria2c`.

Answer (score 1):

Download and learn to use GNU Parallel
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

With single line commands you will be running things in parallel quite soon, not only web page downloads.